# Firebase how do i set and retrieve data user vise?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an app where I am fetching users location and storing it on firebase.Users login credentials i have created on my backend server.So what i have to achieve is when user opens an app i have to set his current location on firebase database.

**Problem i am facing is.**

1) If i put database rules read:false then i m not able to access the database.

2) If i want to set/update location then i have to read database without that how could i set/update locations user vise?

3) If i put rules read:true then it will publicly readable which is not secure.

**So what i exactly want is without any login in firebase how do i set and retrieve data user vise?**

Comment: You can try anonymous auth https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth and still use auth in db rules.

Comment: @sarthak upadhyay - in that case whenever i do login i wl get new UID using anonymous login.What if i have to update my data UID vise?.

Comment: If you are storing data UID-wise you should really implement one of the firebase auth, and use rule - ` "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
` . It would be easier to help if you can explain your particular situation and database structure.

Comment: User is already logged in by using our own credentials.Its not ideal to prompt user again for any firebase auth just to store location.Without firebase auth is it possible to store n retrieve data user-vise?

Comment: Ok so you are a using a non-firebase authentication and want to use firebase db, if that is the case you can use https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth to integrate firebase auth with your auth.

Comment: for that  i hv to create a login to get custom token.How do i manage credentials ?.everytime user gets logged in needs to be login into firebase.

Comment: So when you authenticate your user you create a custom token using firebase admin sdk, pass that token to client and use that to login with firebase. In order to create the token you also pass a uid that you want, this can be uid you use or something else, and you can use that to access firebase features. There is a relevant firecast you probably wanna checkout https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WtYzHTXHBp0